# fscanf string(char array) from index 1

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, scanf

In C++ if you want to input a string and store it in a char array from index 1 you can do something like this:

```
ifstream f("data.in");
char a[100];
f.get(a+1,90);
```

Is there any way you can do this in C (like using fscanf)? Doing this:

```
fscanf(f,"%s",&a+1);
```

or this:

```
fscanf(f,"%s",&(a+1));
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `a` already is a pointer, you don't have to use `&`

Comment: `a+1` should work as well

Comment: use fscanf(f, "%s", a+1);

Comment: `&a + 1` generates an address 100 bytes beyond the start of `a`, because `&a` is `char (*)[100]` in this context, and incrementing a pointer by one jumps it by the size of the object being pointed at (which is an array of 100 bytes in this case).  A good compiler would also complain about the type mismatch between expected `char *` and actual `char (*)[100]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, this way

```
fscanf(f,"%90s",a+1);
```

Comment: It's to limit the number of characters `fscanf` must read, I suppose that's what `f.get(a+1,90)` does.

Comment: Also `&a[1]` for the third argument.